# Postgresql Update with join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I want to join 2 tables and update value of firts table on specified value of 2nd table. I failed using others solutions.

```
UPDATE customers
SET cutoffstop = cutoffstop + '432000'
FROM customers as c
JOIN bluemedia as b ON c.id = b.customerid
WHERE b.orderid = '217201807'
```

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) "*Note that the target table must not appear in the from_list, unless you intend a self-join*" - in other words: do **not** repeat the targe table in the `FROM` clause

Comment: You don't need to repeat the cusomers table in the FROM clause: `UPDATE customers c
SET cutoffstop = cutoffstop + '432000'
FROM  bluemedia as b ON c.id = b.customerid
WHERE b.orderid = '217201807'`

Comment: If cutoffstop is a numerical field: `SET cutoffstop = cutoffstop + 432000` (you cannot add a string to a numerical field)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

General Update Syntax:

```
[ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] with_query [, ...] ]
UPDATE [ ONLY ] table [ [ AS ] alias ]
    SET { column = { expression | DEFAULT } |
          ( column [, ...] ) = ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) } [, ...]
    [ FROM from_list ]
    [ WHERE condition | WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name ]
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

Solution for you problem:

```
UPDATE customers AS c
SET cutoffstop = cutoffstop + 432000
FROM bluemedia as b
WHERE c.id = b.customerid
AND b.orderid = '217201807'
```

For more information on `UPDATE` syntax follow the below link:

> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html

Comment: It gave me an error ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (UPDATE customers AS cust
                                                        ^

Comment: Sorry I have assigned the wrong alias for customers. Now Try Again.

Comment: It keeps throwing me an error ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (UPDATE customers AS c
                                                        ^

Comment: @rafal1137 There is no `COUNT(*)` in your *original* query.

Comment: can you give me full query including `SELECT Count(*) AS part`

Comment: @wildplasser Is there any syntax error in my query?

Comment: I think I found a reason why it was including count(*) with query I was using when inserting query using phpPgAdmin gui I had selected show in result in pages

Answer (score 0):

> Use this query for updation:

```
UPDATE customers
SET cutoffstop = cutoffstop + 432000
FROM bluemedia as b ON customers.id = b.customerid
WHERE b.orderid = '217201807'
```

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SET"
LINE 2: SET cutoffstop = cutoffstop + '432000'
        ^

Comment: please let me know the data type of cutoffstop.. if cutoffstop is numeric or int then remove single  code ....UPDATE customers
SET cutoffstop = cutoffstop + 432000
FROM bluemedia as b ON customers.id = b.customerid
WHERE b.orderid = '217201807'

Comment: @rafal1137: you can't add strings using `+`.  But if those are numbers you need to get rid of the useless single quotes around the number `'432000'` is a varchar, `432000` is an integer

Answer (score 0):

You could use `EXISTS`

```
UPDATE customers c
SET c.cutoffstop = c.cutoffstop + '432000'
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM bluemedia b
        WHERE c.id = b.customerid
            AND b.orderid = '217201807'
        );
```